# What does Skyrim Creation Kit's NPC class do?

Tags: modding, skyrim-modding

I'm trying to change it with the setclass console command Based on the UESP wiki it looks like it just governs stat gain for leveling, but based on the Elder Scrolls wiki it seems to only control their combat AI.

Obviously it does at least one or both of those - what does it actually do, and does it do anything else? __ Ex: if change Lydia from warrior1handed to vigilantcombat1h with the console command 000A2C94.setclass 0010bfef will it have any unintended side effects that aren't immediately apparent other than letting her use the alteration and healing spells I just gave her with console and setting her stats in a way that works for that?

Will it do something weird like mess with her factions or ability to join as my follower? Or mess with her health scaling as she levels? Something hard to notice until alot of time went by?

@desaivv* I was trying to do it with 000A2C94.setclass 0010bfef wasn't sure if it'd cause hidden issues only showing after hours of play or if i made a new character with the same bat file. but the creation kit sounds like an idea too, i'll have to see how complicated it is. it might just show what it'd do or have some easier way to change her behavior to add spells. I'll try it and see if anything obvious shows up short term just wasn't sure if it had known long term problems

Comment: If you can change something like that you could play test it. _How do you_ change it? Maybe _I_ could play test it.

Comment: Go to this website it gives you all the basic and some advance info about it
http://tesalliance.org/forums/index.php?/topic/4655-introduction-creation-kit-basics/

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out that the "class" is a remnant from the old Elder Scrolls system, in which it defines what skills cause you to level up (and those would start at a higher level at the beginning of the game). I also once saw in the Strategy Guide that it has guidelines for different "class" builds. It sounds like this is the sort of thing "class" is referring to in this context.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the Wikipedia definition of a Class

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)

> In object-oriented programming, a class is a construct that is used to create instances of itself – referred to as class instances, class objects, instance objects or simply objects. A class defines constituent members which enable its instances to have state and behavior.[1] Data field members (member variables or instance variables) enable a class instance to maintain state. Other kinds of members, especially methods, enable the behavior of class instances. Classes define the type of their instances.[2]
>   A class usually represents a noun, such as a person, place or thing, or something nominalized. For example, a "Banana" class would represent the properties and functionality of bananas in general. A single, particular banana would be an instance of the "Banana" class, an object of the type "Banana".

**Here  you will find basics on classes in the Creationkit**
http://www.creationkit.com/Class

> The Class Form, used on the Actor Stats Tab, allows you to specify how an Actor will distribute the attribute and skill bonuses they gain based on their level. It also affects a few other systems, such as Bleedout for Essential Actors and skill training for Trainers.
>   Class is only applicable to NPCs. It has no meaning for the player.

**Data Fields  X-- X-- X--X-- X-- X--X-- X-- X--X-- X-- X--X-- X-- X--**

**1. ID:** The Form ID of the object.

**2. Full Name:** A label to identify the class. Not displayed in game.

**3. Auto-Calc Other:**

**3.1 Recharge:** Not used.

**3.2 Training:** If checked, this NPC is a Skill Trainer, and can train the player in the  selected skill to the selected maximum value.

**4. Bleedout Default:** If the Actor is Essential or Protected, and their health falls below  this ratio, they enter the Bleedout state
    and drop to one knee until their health recovers. This is typically
    set to 0.1, which means that Bleedout occurs when the Actor's health
    falls below 10%.

**5. Voice Points:** The pool of 'Voice Points' the Actor has for Shouts. Has no effect if the Actor has no Shouts.

**6. Description:** Not displayed in the game.

**7. Menu Image:** Not used.

> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

**Here you will find the info that governs stat gaining etc.** 
http://www.creationkit.com/Stats_Tab